# sqlite combine select all from multiple columns

Tags: sql, select

How to combine many select queries into 1 statement in SQLite?

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE condition1
SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE condition2
SELECT * FROM Table3 WHERE condition3
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `UNION` to combine the results of the three queries.

`UNION` will remove duplicate leaving on unique rows on the final result. If you want to keep the duplicate rows, use `UNION ALL`.

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE condition1 
UNION
SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE condition2 
UNION
SELECT * FROM Table3 WHERE condition3
```

**caveat**: the number of columns (*as well as the data type*) must match on each select statement.

**UPDATE 1**

based on your comment below, You are looking for `JOIN`,

```
SELECT  a.*, b.*, c.*
FROM    table1 a
        INNER JOIN table2 b
            ON a.ColName = b.ColName
        INNER JOIN table3 c
            ON a.ColName = c.ColName
-- WHERE    .. add conditions here ..
```

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: Sadly, all my tables have different structures

Comment: If that's the case then you need atleast to select the important once.. Can you give sanple records with your desired result so we can find another way?

Comment: Or you could add "NULL as colname" for each missing column.  You didn't say what "combine" means.  If you describe what you're trying to do and *why*, you might elicit more helpful answers.

Comment: I desire to retreive all data (exept id) from 3 tables to create such structure:

Comment: Can you atleast include the structures of your table?

Comment: sry 5minutes time was up, didnt manage to add structure :P

[[table1.value1[0],table1.value2[0],table1.value3[0],...,[table2.value2[x] where table2.value1[x]==table1.value1[0]],[table3.value2[x],table3.value3[x],table3.value4[x],... where table3.value1[x]==table1.value1[0]],[table1.value1[1],table1.value2[1],table1.value3[1],...,[table2.value2[y] where table2.value1[y]==table1.value1[1]],[table3.value2[y],table3.value3[y],table3.value4[y],... where table3.value1[y]==table1.value1[1]],...]

Comment: Basicly, all values from table1 + value from table2 where table2.alias == table1.alias + all values from table3 where table3.alias == table1.alias

Comment: so basically, you don't need `UNION` but `JOIN`.

Answer (score 1):

Your can also query also like 
SELECT * FROM users where bday > '1970-05-20' 
UNION ALL SELECT * FROM users where bday < '1970-01-20'