# SQLite + Python: How to use parameters for SELECT and UNION?

Tags: python, sqlite

I want to combine multi SELECT results into one statement.

I searched on SO but didnot found the answer. But I found a similar one: [sqlite combine select all from multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15720707/sqlite-combine-select-all-from-multiple-columns)

The difference between the above question and mine is that I have parameters in the statement.

Hier are my codes...

```
cur.execute('''
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE ColA = ? 
UNION
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE ColB = ? 
UNION
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE ColC = ?
(ValueA, ValueB, ValueC,)''')
```

The ValueA, ValueB, ValueC are parameters.

But it didnot work. How could I change the codes? Thanks!

Comment: Just to satiate my own curiosity, any reason you don't want to select these all with one query, like `WHERE ColA = ValueA OR ColB = ValueB OR ColC = ValueC`? The `UNION` can give you duplicate rows, but perhaps that's the answer to the question I'm asking.

Comment: @Santi Thanks for your comment. If I do as you write, the results would be different. Besides, I think the command UNION ALL gives duplicated rows.

Comment: Parameters are used only when you are accessing SQL from a host language. Show that code.

Comment: @CL. Yes, you are right. I am using Python. The parameters are from python as well.

Comment: @CL. I pasted the code I wrote in Python.

Comment: @doglas You need to re-read the documentation on how query parameters work in Python. They don't go in the SQL query string.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo Thanks. I know. I read and tried a lot.

Comment: @doglas - So is your question resolved? Just move the values to params arg of execute: `cur.execute(<sql statement>, (ValueA, ValueB, ValueC))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Query parameters do not belong into the query string but must be a second parameter of `execute`:

```
cur.execute('''
    SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE ColA = ? 
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE ColB = ? 
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE ColC = ?''',
    (ValueA, ValueB, ValueC))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe this can help you:

`cur.execute('SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE colc =(?,?,?)', valueA,ValueB,ValueC)`